# Auto check saved value of radio button on view load

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have created an input form, I am using textboxes and radio button to input fields in my database, I need some help in Edit mode, when user opens the form, I want to select the saved value in my radio button group. I am unable to do that, please review my view and suggest.

```
<RadioButtonGroup columns="5"  id="rb_PC" selected="{ path: 'Item' }">
    <buttons>
     <RadioButton id="rb_itm1" groupName="itm1" text="Item 1"/>
     <RadioButton id="rb_itm2" groupName="itm2" text="Item 2"/>
     <RadioButton id="rb_itm3" groupName="itm3" text="Item 3"/>
     <RadioButton id="rb_itm4" groupName="itm4" text="Item 4"/>
     <RadioButton id="rb_itm5" groupName="itm5" text="Item 5"/>
    </buttons>
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no property `selected` in `RadioButtonGroup`.

I would try the following:

1. Bind your Items collection to RadioButtonGroup [buttons](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.12/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.RadioButtonGroup.html#getButtons) aggregation
2. In each RadioButton check for selection

In the example below I used a JSON model with an ItemsCollection, each item has a Name and an Id property. The model contains property named SelectedItemId referencing the selected Item. Selection is checked with [expression binding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0):

```
<RadioButtonGroup columns="5" id="rd_PC" buttons="{/ItemsCollection}">
    <buttons>
        <RadioButton text="{Name}" selected="{= ${Id} === ${/SelectedItemId}}"/>
    </buttons>
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the closest that I can get to your example
http://jsbin.com/metocec/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MVC</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.table"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
    </script>

    <script id="oView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="myView.Template"
      xmlns="sap.m" 
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
      <VBox>
        <RadioButtonGroup columns="5" selectedIndex="{/radio}">
          <RadioButton text="Item 1"/>
          <RadioButton text="Item 2"/>
          <RadioButton text="Item 3"/>
          <RadioButton text="Item 4"/>
          <RadioButton text="Item 5"/>
      </RadioButtonGroup>
      <Input value="{/input}" />
      </VBox>
  </mvc:View>
    </script>

  </head>

  <body class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

controller

```
sap.ui.define([
  'jquery.sap.global',
  'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
  'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
  "use strict";

  var oController = Controller.extend("myView.Template", {
    onInit: function(oEvent) {
      this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
        radio: 2, // do attachRequestCompleted to set the index accordingly
        input: 'test'
      }));
    }
  });

  return oController;
});

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: jQuery('#oView').html()
});

oView.placeAt('content');
```